# cspack behaviour differs from msbuild

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Using Visual Studio 2012, Azure SDK 2.1, I am trying to figure out the best way to create the csx folder for running in the azure emulator. My understanding is that the csx folder is not created until I package the Azure project. I can create a package manually from Visual Studio, but this is not an option for an automated build. The other option is to create the package using the msbuild command line. This seems a bit heavy handed as it will actually do a build which is more time consuming than just repackaging.

So, I thought that cspack might be a more lightweight option. However, when I call cspack with the following command line:

cspack.exe ServiceDefinition.csdef /copyOnly

I get the error: Need to specify the physical directory for the virtual path 'Web/' of role MyProjWeb.

But, I don't do anything like that when using msbuild. I have read a bunch of things about specifying the physical directory and some of the confusion that it can cause. So, I would prefer not to use it unless absolutely necessary, especially since I don't need to specify this when building from msbuild.

So, my main question is what is msbuild doing that cspack is not doing and how do I do the same with cspack?
My other question is, what is the easiest way to generate the csx folder for testing in the azure emulator?

**Edit - Resolution**

I thought that I would put down how I resolved this here in case it helps someone else. The big answer to my question (thanks to Chandermani and some other reading) is that CSPack with /copyOnly is basically a fancy xcopy to a folder structure according to some rules. If not using /copyOnly it then also does a fancy zip to create a package. Not complaining, it is fine that it is simple, but it is good to know this at the outset. You can use it for packaging anything for azure it is not tied to what can be built in Visual Studio, e.g. a PHP site. Using msbuild has the added benefit of only copying that files that are part of your web site deployment.

So, what I found when I got CSPack working and pointed at the mvc project folder is that it copied everything including source files. Which is not what I wanted. The solution that I could find is to first package the web site then point CSPack at the packaged files. If you do down this path then [this link](http://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/automating-azure-1-4-packaging-using-msbuild-and-cspack/) is very valuable as it describes it step by step.

So, it was either having an msbuild post-step in the Web project to package the files and then a post-step in my Azure project to cspack it or to have an msbuild post-step in my azure project to create the package (do  cspack with the benefit of only including my web deployment files). Well, it seemed simpler and less error prone to just to have the one post step and let msbuild do the heavy lifting. So, the post step in my azure project is something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe" /devfabric:shutdown > NUL
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe" /devstore:shutdown > NUL
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug set CONSTANTSPARAMETER=DEBUG
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release set CONSTANTSPARAMETER=
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe $(ProjectDir)$(ProjectFileName) /t:clean;publish /p:Configuration=$(ConfigurationName) /p:TargetProfile=cloud /p:OutputPath=bin\Cloud$(ConfigurationName) /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:overwritereadonlyfiles=true /p:DefineConstants="%CONSTANTSPARAMETER%" /verbosity:minimal /p:PostBuildEvent=
```

The first two lines shut down the compute and storage emulator.

The next two lines set the preprocessor constants. I found that #if DEBUG was no longer taking effect when built using the msbuild line. I think that this is safety protection that DEBUG is stripped when creating a package. I only ever use the package that is created by an automated build system, so it is safe for me to keep the DEBUG constant.

The actual msbuild line has a number of switches. I'll describe the unusual ones:

/p:PostBuildEvent=

If we don't set the postBuildEvent to empty then the same post step will keep getting called forever. And ever...

/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0

Those clever guys at Microsoft made it possible to open projects with both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Which is great, but can bring great sadness when you run msbuild from the command line and end up with nasty MSB4019 error messages because it is looking in the wrong Visual Studio folder for the Azure tools.

Also, note that that I use the cloud profile. Since I am only after the csx files it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I use local or cloud at this point. When I run in azure I specify ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg.

**Edit:** In the end I took this out of the post step and put in my automated build. My original intention was that running the tests from my dev machine would be the same as my automated build, but the post step took too long and the views were sourced from the obj folder rather than the proj folder when running under the debugger which meant I had to copy across when making changes on the fly.

**Unanswered questions**

It would still be good to understand how msbuild does things to reduce knowledge friction when dabbling in this area. Does it create a package for the website and pass it to CSPack? Or does it parse the project files and then pass some crazy arguments to CSPack? Also when you run an azure project in the debugger, it runs in the emulator with only the binaries in the csx folder (not the images, etc). How does it do that? It would be great to see some description with pictures of the Azure build pipeline with that showed the lifecycle all the way to deployment. That might also explain why there are two copies of the binaries. Also, this would have been a whole lot easier if Visual studio had a project flag like packageOnBuild for the Azure project with options to do a copyOnly or to create a package. I see no point in uneaten cake. **Edit:** There is a DeployOnBuild setting that can be added to csproj.

Finally, as I mentioned the whole purpose of this is to get a csx folder that I can point the emulator at so that I can run my unit tests on my dev machine. I do the formal packaging on a build machine so don't really need it in Visual Studio. So, really I don't want to package anything and was hoping that there was an easier way of achieving all this.

Answer (score 1):

Since msbuild uses the the azure project file to perform the build, it can derive a lot of information form the project file.

For cspack, the assumption is the role code has been compiled and is available for packaging. Since cspack does not depend upon  project file, it needs a explicit information for the code path of the the web\workerrole project. The csdef file does not contain any such information. I suggest if you want to use cspack. Look at its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx) and try to create a package for emulator deployment from command line (CopyOnly option). Once you find the correct syntax you can embed it in you build script.

Comment: Thanks, I already read that documentation. What I was wondering was, since I didn't specify a physical directory in Visual Studio or any of the azure configuration files, why is it that it is not required for msbuild but is for cspack? Or, asked differently where is msbuild getting this information from? Also, is there an easier way to generate the csx files since I don't really want to create a package, I just want to run in the emulator?

Comment: I am not sure how exactly it gets, but when you create a azure project,you also add the web project to it, the ccproj file contains to path to the project, so it would not be hard to find the path give all the details are there in .ccproj file. For running in emulator cspack with CopyOnly works.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense that it would get it from the ccproj. I am already using CopyOnly as per the example in my question. I guess I will need to go with that for the moment.