# The cspack throw one exception that: the file path 'out:c:\pweb.cspkg' contains invalid characters or is too long

Tags: azure

I'm a fresh man in this topic. Now I'm trying to simulate the services before I deploy my web role to the cloud server.

So I try to use the Computer Emulator and create the package at first through the cspack.exe

It throws the exception that the file path 'out:c:\pweb.cspkg' contains invalid characters or is too long.

Below is my work steps:

1, build the package by cspack.exe

```
cspack c:\mydefinition role:pweb sites:pweb out:c:\pweb.cspkg then it throw exception as you know
```

2, once the package builded successfully, I would try to attach it to the Computer Emulator by csrun.

But now I'm stop at the first step here.

Could you give me some help. Thank you.

Regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are leaving off the / on the command parameters.  the role, sites and out parameters should all be proceeded with a /.

check the command line help by typing the following: **cspack.exe /?**

Also, if you are attempting to create a package that the local emulator will use you need to ensure to include the /copyOnly parameter.  Looking at the [MSDN documentation on CSPack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx) it states as follows:

"*If /copyOnly is not specified, this option specifies the file name for the application package. If no file name is specified, the application package is created as .cspkg.*"

In the [MSDN Documentation for CSRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433001.aspx) is states as follows:

"*Before you can use CSRun to deploy an application to the compute emulator, you must run the CSPack Command-Line Tool with the /copyOnly option to prepare the application for local deployment. When CSPack runs with the /copyOnly option, a directory layout is created for the application in the form required by the compute emulator.*"

You may also find the content of the this other SO question useful: [cspack behaviour differs from msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117994/cspack-behaviour-differs-from-msbuild).  Not so much about the question, but the differences in what cspack is doing regarding creating a directory or creating the actual package file for running locally or for deployment to Azure.